# Pass instance as an argument to a function and then display the instance data in the function

Tags: c++, function, object, arguments

I want to be able to pass `pixelOne` as the argument to the `showPixelDetails()` function. The only way I've found of doing it so far is below. How do I pass `pixelOne` as an argument to that function?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Pixel
{
public:
    float xCoord;
    float yCoord;
    double brightness;

    void showPixelDetail();
};

void Pixel::showPixelDetail()
{
    cout<< xCoord << endl;
    cout<< yCoord << endl;
    cout<< brightness << endl;
}

int main()
{
    Pixel pixelOne;

    icon myIcon;

    pixelOne.xCoord=1;
    pixelOne.yCoord=1;
    pixelOne.brightness=15;

    pixelOne.showPixelDetail();

    return 0;
}
```

`pixelOne` needs to be the argument I pass. When I try to pass it, `xCoord`, `yCoord` and `brightness` aren't declared in the scope. I know why, but there must be a way for them to be passed with the `pixelOne` as the argument.

Comment: There's no need to pass anything to the `pixelOne.showPixelDetail();`, it already does that using the `pixelOne` instance.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is fine already, but you seem to want to have a function that accepts a `Pixel` argument instead of using a member function with implicit `this`. In that case, move the function outside the class and add a parameter:

```
class Pixel{
  public:
    float xCoord;
    float yCoord;
    double brightness;
};

void showPixelDetail(const Pixel& pixel) {
    std::cout << pixel.xCoord << '\n';
    std::cout << pixel.yCoord << '\n';
    std::cout << pixel.brightness << '\n';
}

int main() {
    Pixel pixelOne;
    
    pixelOne.xCoord=1;
    pixelOne.yCoord=1;
    pixelOne.brightness=15;

    showPixelDetail(pixelOne);
}
```

[live link](https://wandbox.org/permlink/OI55R6ilCprgqOfC)